# What is the word or term used to describe when a simple job is made unnecessarily difficult?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology

As when someone at work makes the job more difficult than it needs to be just because of the way they are and their attitude towards the work, and not just for them but for others too.
Hello - thank you all for your efforts.  It occurs to me that it might be better to put this question to the workplace section as I'm looking for a situation-specific term that an employment expert might use.

Comment: Are you looking for a term to describe the character of a person which causes them to create more work, the effect they have on the work, or the increase in work itself? Could you write a sentence with a blank for us to fill in?

Comment: Mountain out of molehill perhaps?

Comment: *Perfectionist* comes to mind but my favorite is *martinette* as it captures not just the issues with overcomplication but also micromanaging people in the process of overcomplicating. People tinged with obssessive-compulsive disorder(s) will exhibit this tendency as well.

Comment: awaiting clarification from OP ... maybe rube goldberg

Comment: Deconstruction: Separate, Difficulty, from Attitude and Results. Controlling defines *makes the job more difficult*. Uncooperative defines *makes the job more difficult that (than) it needs to be...for others too* .  Results are not stated, and that makes a big difference in the nature of the actions. It is easy to misjudge issues related to group dynamics without knowing their end results.

Comment: @Jim I was going to give your answer, but you should since it was your suggestion. I think **overcomplicate** is the best choice here.

Answer (score 3):

You might try ***overcomplicate*** as in

“Todd tends to *overcomplicate* everything he does.”

Oxford Dictionaries defines it as:

> [***overcomplicate***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overcomplicate):
>   Make (something) more complicated than necessary.
>   *‘the basic idea is quite simple but some people tend to overcomplicate it’*

Answer (score 0):

**Exacerbate.** Aggravate. Complicate. Convolute. Perplex.

Answer (score 0):

***Obfuscate***.

Not quite the same meaning as "making more difficult", but with the same effect.